# SwiftUI How to align a view that's larger than screen width

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui

I'm drawing a table using SwiftUI that has too many rows and columns to fit into the screen width / height. In this case, I cannot align the view as leading but is somehow always centered. How can I align them top leading?
Here is the view that draws the table:

```
struct TableView: View {
    let columnCount: Int = 9
    let rowCount: Int = 14

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal], showsIndicators: false) {
                GridStack(rows: self.rowCount, columns: self.columnCount) { row, col in
                    Text("ROW \(String(row)) COL \(String(col))")
                        .frame(width: 120)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is GridStack:

```
struct GridStack<Content: View>: View {
    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int
    let content: (Int, Int) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(0 ..< rows) { row in
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.columns) { column in
                        self.content(row, column)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding([.top, .bottom], 20)
    }

    init(rows: Int, columns: Int, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Content) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like in the app. Notice the edges don't fit inside the screen. Even if I try to scroll there, it just bounces back.

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach (and direction of improvements, because I did not test all cases and possibilities)

*Note: if you select only one `ScrollView` axis it does content alignment automatically, otherwise it is now I assume confused, but does not have capability to be configured. So below might be considered as temporary workaround.*

The idea is to read grid content offset via `GeometryReader` recalculation of frame in `.global.` coordinate space and mitigate it explicitly.

Also there is a try to invalidate and handle offset depending on device orientation (probably not ideal, but as a first try), because they are different.

[image]
[image]

```
import Combine

struct TableView: View {
    let columnCount: Int = 9
    let rowCount: Int = 14

    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero

    private let orientationPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
                GridStack(rows: self.rowCount, columns: self.columnCount) { row, col in
                    Text("ROW \(String(row)) COL \(String(col))")
                        .fixedSize()
                        .frame(width: 150)
                }
                .background(rectReader())
                .offset(x: offset)
            }
        }
        .onReceive(orientationPublisher) { _ in
            self.offset = .zero
        }
    }

    func rectReader() -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { (geometry) -> AnyView in
            let offset = -geometry.frame(in: .global).minX
            if self.offset == .zero {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.offset = offset
                }
            }
            return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.clear))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great and solves the problem, thank you! As an addition, I renamed your `offset` to `offsetX` and also created an `offsetY`. So I can also assign an offset to y-axis in case both the rows and columns are too large to fit into view.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. The updated offset variable never gets set in .offset(x:offset). It is a state variable so theoretically it should work, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After several days of trying, finally found a easiest way to solve. Hope this can help.

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical], showsIndicators: true) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Range(1...10)) { x in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(Range(1...10)) { y in
                            Text("\(x), \(y)")
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
                        }
                        Spacer() //  1
                    }
                }
                Spacer() //  2
            }.frame(minWidth: geo.size.width, minHeight: geo.size.height)  //  3
        }
    }
}
```

[image]