# SwiftUI: How to set position of ScrollView to Top Left? (both scrolls is enabled)

Tags: swift, macos, scroll, scrollview, swiftui

```
ScrollView(){
//no matter
}
```

Position is Top Left, but content will have smaller width than I needed

(2 strings in red rectangle must be single string, so need to enable both scrolls )

[image]

---

```
ScrollView([Axis.Set.horizontal, Axis.Set.vertical]) {
//no matter
}
```

In this case ScrollView's content have correct size for me.

But position of scrollView's content is centred ( both: horizontally and vertically )

How can I change default position to Top Left in case of ScrollView configured to both scrolls?

Comment: This article might help you: https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/

Comment: Please check this way if can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113955/5655043

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update: Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4

The issue is still there, but now the solution is simpler using ScrollViewReader:

```
struct TestTwoAxisScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { sp in
            ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { _ in
                        self.row()
                    }
                }
                .border(Color.green)
                .id("root")
            }
            .border(Color.gray)
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                sp.scrollTo("root", anchor: .topLeading)
            }
        }
    }

    func row() -> some View {
        Text(test)
            .border(Color.red) // uncomment to see border
    }
}
```

#### Original

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / macOS 10.15.3

Demo:

[image: demo]

Code (complete testable module, borders are added for better visibility of each component):

```
import SwiftUI

let test = """
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12118" systemVersion="16A323" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
"""

struct ScrollViewHelper: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ScrollViewHelper>) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView(frame: .zero)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // << must be async, so view got into view hierarchy
            view.enclosingScrollView?.contentView.scroll(to: .zero)
            view.enclosingScrollView?.reflectScrolledClipView(view.enclosingScrollView!.contentView)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ScrollViewHelper>) {
    }
}

struct TestTwoAxisScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) { _ in
                    self.row()
                }
            }
            .background(ScrollViewHelper()) // << active part !!
            .border(Color.green) // uncomment to see border
        }
        .border(Color.gray)
        .padding()
    }

    func row() -> some View {
        Text(test)
            .border(Color.red) // uncomment to see border
    }
}

struct TestTwoAxisScrollView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestTwoAxisScrollView()
    }
}
```