# How to align ScrollView content to top when both axes are used?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, lazyvstack

Here's a simple example:

```swift
struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical], showsIndicators: false, content: {
            LazyVStack(content: {
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { count in
                    Text("Item \(count)")
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that when both axes are used (`[.horizontal, .vertical]`), `ScrollView` automatically **centers** any content inside vertically and horizontally. I have a big data table in the `ScrollView`, and I need it to be aligned to **top** instead but I couldn't figure out how to do this. Usual stuff with `Vstack`s and `Spacer`s doesn't work here at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59739911/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi it helps for the X axis, but for Y (which I need) no. When scrolling vertically, items start to suddenly disappear (because of `LazyVStack`, but it happens right in the scrollview, like it ignores the fact that the item that's about to disappear is still visible in the scrollview). I hope my explanation makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an example, with a `Slider` so you can interactively test it.

This works by making sure the content within the `ScrollView` is *at least* as high as the `ScrollView` itself. This leads to the content filling the whole vertical space, so it will start at the top.

Code:

```
struct Example: View {
    @State private var count: Double = 10

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical], showsIndicators: false, content: {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(1 ... Int(count), id: \.self) { count in
                                Text("Item \(count)")
                            }
                        }

                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    }
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width)
                    .frame(minHeight: geo.size.height)
                })
            }

            Slider(value: $count, in: 10 ... 100)
        }
    }
}
```

In some cases you may need to use `.frame(minWidth: geo.size.width)` rather than just `width`. This can be in the same line as the `minHeight`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Works great for `VStack`s, but it must work with `LazyVStack` too, because there might be tons of items.

Comment: @Randex Ah sorry, temporarily changed that. I'll try get it working with `LazyVStack`.

Comment: Works great, thank you very much! Your first solution made me thinking that I need to manually calculate the `minLength` of the spacer, but your final solution turns out to be much cleaner than mine :)

Comment: @Randex While trying to figure out, I was getting in a mess with 2 `GeometryReader`s... and then I realised I could make it much simpler doing this

Comment: Ok, so I tested it a bit more in my project where I have a really wide table in that scroll view, and I noticed that when the content is wider than the width of the screen, it doesn't allow you to scroll horizontally because of `.frame(width: geo.size.width)`. To fix that you need to use `minWidth` instead. And we also can put all this into one `.frame` call: `.frame(minWidth: geo.size.width, minHeight: geo.size.height)`

Comment: Great work! Has anyone got this working with LazyVStack pinned section headers?
the top of the header is clipped for me doesn't look right